# Can sunlight be utilised as a mining "laser drill"?

Tags: physics, engineering, asteroid-belt, sunlight

Can sunlight be used to bore a hole into an asteroid in the belt, so metals with a high enough melting point are left behind, ablated off for easy recovery? Or is the sun too far away?

Comment: Should be possible, read this link for a easy to understand explanation https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To melt your asteroid you need heat. A lot of heat. But the sun is very hot (1.57×10^7 Kelvin, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun)); the sun is also roundish, so you can't really focus all of that heat, but it's probably more than hot enough.

So the question then is how big a lenses can you make? If you can make a big enough lens, and keep it pointing the right direction, yes, you can melt the asteroid. Not very practical.

A related or similar question has been asked before on xkcd's what if. [Fire From Moonlight](https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/).

Comment: The surface temperature is not anywhere close to that, but with a few tousand degrees it should be hot enough.

Comment: The concept is known as a [solar furnace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_furnace); they don't use lenses, but rather arrays of mirrors. Positioned out in space, arrays could be as big as needed, and increased distance from the Sun just means you need more of them.

Comment: @AnthonyX's comment is an answer, and a correct one.  Inverse square law, and the stats of the Odeillo furnace, say how big you'd need one in the Belt.

Comment: @AnthonyX Essentially the same principle. Focusing light. _More of them_ just means more mirror area, essentially the same as a wider lens. Albeit, a fair tidy bit lighter than your common glass lens taken up to 11, thats for sure.